# Having trouble clicking on Yahoo UI (YUI) checkbox with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, yui

I am trying to use selenium to webscrape a page but I cannot get it to work on a checkbox menu. I have tried to .click() on every element and all of them return "ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable". It seems like the checkbox is made with YUI but after looking through those scripts I cannot find much help. Does anyone know how I can interact with these elements?

Here is the website code:

```
<span class="yui-button yui-push-button multiSelectButton" id="subjAreaButton"><span class="first-child"><button type="button" tabindex="0" title="Click to view options" id="subjAreaButton-button">1 Selected</button></span></span>
   <div id="subjAreaMultiSelect" class="multiSelect yui-module yui-overlay yui-overlay-hidden" title="" style="visibility: hidden; display: block; z-index: 10; left: 455px; top: 132px; opacity: 1;">
    <div class="bd">
      <div id="subjAreaMultiSelectOptionsScroller" class="multiSelectOptionsScroller" style="height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
         <div id="subjAreaMultiSelectOptions" class="multiSelectOptions">
            <div class="selectLinksDiv">
               
               
                  <span id="subjAreaMultiSelectClearButton" class="selectLink">
                     <img src="./Student Registration _ Schedule Search_files/redX.gif" height="12"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="subjAreaMultiSelectBox.clearAll()">Clear all</a>
                  </span>
               
            </div>
            
               
               
               <div id="subjAreaMultiSelectOptionContainer0" class="multiSelectOptionContainer" title="A&amp;S College Core">
                  <input id="subjAreaMultiSelectOption0" title="A&amp;S College Core" name="searchCriteria.subjectAreaCodes" type="checkbox" value="CORE" class="multiSelectOption" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="5">
                  <span id="subjAreaMultiSelectOptionLabel0" class="multiSelectOptionLabel">A&amp;S College Core</span>
               </div>
            
               
               
               <div id="subjAreaMultiSelectOptionContainer1" class="multiSelectOptionContainer" title="African American and Diaspora Studies">
                  <input id="subjAreaMultiSelectOption1" title="African American and Diaspora Studies" name="searchCriteria.subjectAreaCodes" type="checkbox" value="AADS" class="multiSelectOption">
                  <span id="subjAreaMultiSelectOptionLabel1" class="multiSelectOptionLabel">African American and Diaspora Studies</span>
               </div>
```